Regular expressions in dm script
Does the Digital Micrograph scripting language have any built-in support (not including Python) for regular expressions?
Looking through the built-in documentation I do not see any reference to regex usage, but I know the documentation is very limited.

No, (at least to my knowledge), there is no inbuilt regEx support in DM-script.
